# linker stage: undefined reference

Tags: c++, class, reference, undefined

I already read like 15 of the undefined reference topics here and used google too to find a valid answer, but there was non that really helped.

I wrote a 1D and 2D simple storage class which allows rapid loop through by directly accessing the data (plus some convenience accessors). Here the 1D goes (2D is pretty much the same, just 2D)

Header:

```
#ifndef MULTI1_H
#define MULTI1_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

template <class T>
class Multi1
{
public:
    Multi1(int32_t size_ = -1);
    ~Multi1();
    void set(T val, int32_t pos);
    T& operator[] (int32_t pos) const;
    T& at(int32_t pos) const;
    int32_t m_size;
    T *m_data;
};

#endif // MULTI1_H
```

Body:

```
#include "multi1.h"

template <class T>
Multi1<T>::Multi1(int32_t size_) :
  m_size(size_),
  m_data(NULL)
{
  if (size_>0)
    m_data = (T *) malloc (sizeof(T)*size_);
  else
     m_size = 0;
}

template <class T>
Multi1<T>::~Multi1()
{
  if (m_data!=NULL)
    free (m_data);
}

template <class T>
void Multi1<T>::set(T val, int32_t pos)
{
  m_data[pos] = val;
}

template <class T>
T& Multi1<T>::operator[](int32_t pos) const
{
  return m_data[pos];
}

template <class T>
T& Multi1<T>::at(int32_t pos) const
{
  return m_data[pos];
}


./build/main.o: In function `setupDemo(Multi1<voCam*>&, Multi1<voBoard*>&, Multi2<voBoardObservation*>&)':
./src/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `Multi1<voCam*>::operator[](int) const'
./src/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `Multi1<voCam*>::operator[](int) const'
./src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `Multi1<voBoard*>::operator[](int) const'
./src/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `Multi1<voBoard*>::operator[](int) const'
./src/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `Multi1<voCam*>::operator[](int) const'
....
```

I checked the includes like 5 times, and I recently got pretty used to C programming where I can keep things like linker vendetta from my neck.

Note: I am compiling with g++, linker flags are `-lstdc++ -lm`

Comment: Any particular reason you're using deprecated headers?

Comment: I can’t believe that of 15 discussions of the “undefined reference” error none discussed your particular problem. This is so common that it should be in the first few hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you defined?

```
Multi1<voCam*>::operator[](int) const
```

Ah ok, You have it, You should have template declaration and definition in the same header file.

Comment: This is not an answer. (Though, with an appropriate disclaimer, it could be a good rhetorical one!)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: At first I didn't notice there indeed was one defined and hence thought that was the problem. Anyhow I had modifed it just as I noticed there was one.

Answer (score 4):

Did you put your template functions inside the header file?

So 
`template <class T>
void Multi1<T>::set(T val, int32_t pos)
{
  m_data[pos] = val;
}`

should be inside your multi.h header file.

Comment: yes. see http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/32577/ - basically, the compiler needs to know which types the template parameters will be instantiated with, so this information must be available before linking.

Comment: is this the only way of fixing it, by pushing all methods to the header or what?

Comment: @fearlesstost now thats a usefull answer, ty!

Comment: @drahnr: Yes, that's the only sensible solution. Templates are not *code*, they are a *code generation tool*. However, you have to compile actual code, so you must provide the definitions of the actual *template instances*. You *could* in theory put explicit instantiations into one single source file, but that'd be fairly confusing.